# What dynamic asynchronous web server framework to use?

Tags: python, server, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol

Should I use flask or Quart or just crossbar to serve dynamic and asynchronous web page ? I need websocket with RPC and PubSub.

I usually work on database with sqlalchemy , and I like brython instead of javascript.
I'd like to avoid Node.js if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a [list of implementations here](https://wamp-proto.org/implementations.html#routers)

I'm planning to use Node.js and the Crossbar.io documentation is very helpful.  Seems like a good choice.